# Remove entry in TOC for longtblr (tabularray )

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, tabularray

I have a table using a tabularray package and I am unable to remove it form my TOC. In the manual (pdf link below) they advise to use a command `entry = none` but I literally get then an entry:

> 1 none......... page no.

https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf

I also tried the following trick: `\captionsetup[table]{list=no}` but it didn't work.

Do you know how to remove it?

Comment: Did you delete the `.lot` file after adding `entry=none`?

Comment: The `entry=none` is for `longtblr` where the caption is generated by `tabularray`. On the other hand, if you have a `tblr` in a `table` environment, and you use the `caption` package, you should use `\caption[]{Caption text}`. The `[]` is supposed to suppress the entry in the list of tables.

Comment: The problem turned out to be an outdated texlive version, see comments below the answer

Answer (score 0):

The most bizzare thing happened. I duplicated my project in overleaf so that I have two seemingly the same documents. The second, however, doesn't have the TOC entry when `entry = none` is used. I have no idea how this works...

Comment: If you create a new project, it will automatically use texlive2022. Your old project will use whatever texlive versions was the default when it was created. If it is older than ~ this August, it will use an old texlive version.

Comment: Can you add the .log file of your old project to your question?

Comment: Interesting, sure I uploaded the log messgae here: https://we.tl/t-YJMmiTFn2O

Comment: Indeed an old texlive2021, which included an old version of tabularray, which did not yet have this feature

Comment: Okay, that's good to know, thanks a lot!